# How to patch or set value for particular input field in angular reactive forms

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

Working on reactive nested forms where initially data is null because data is coming for some fields from the dialog box(when dialog box is closed.)

I need to set values for the particular fields of the form when data gets available without causing form reset.

This is the payload structure

```
data = {
  name: "", 
  imagesList: [
    {
      imagePath: "",
      imageDescription: [
        {
          language: "",
          text: ""
        }
      ]
    },
  ],
  }
```

Corresponding FormArray Structure for reference

[image]

In the below code ** openImagesDialog()** functions are receiving the data which is coming from the observable response when subscribing after dialog box is closed.

```
  openImagesDialog(){
    this.companyNewsDialogServiceService.imagesListDataRecieved.subscribe(res => {
      console.log("imagetest",res)
      this.modalResponseData = res
      this.imageFilePath = this.modalResponseData.data.filepath
      this.imageDescText = this.modalResponseData.data.text
      this.imageFileName = this.modalResponseData.data.filename
      console.log("imagedata", this.imageFilePath)
      console.log("imageDescText", this.imageDescText)
      this.data.imagesList.forEach(x => {
        x.imagePath = this.imageFilePath
        x.imageDescription.forEach(y => {
          y.text = this.imageDescText
        })
      })
      this.createAppForm = this.setFormGroup(this.data);
      console.log("image-form-data", this.createAppForm.value)
    })
    this.companyNewsDialogServiceService.confirmImagesListDialog({
      title: 'Images List',
      description: 'Images List Description',
      imageSrc: "",
      modalFormData: this.companyNewsDialogServiceService.recivedFormData,
      showText: true
    }); 
  }
```

Below code is for formation of the nested form structure as per the payload where i'm assigning setFormGroup() function to createAppForm (formgroup) like this.createAppForm = this.setFormGroup(this.data); inside the constructor

form structure code

```
  get imagesListFormData(){
    return <FormArray>this.createAppForm.get('imagesList')
  }

  getImageDescriptionFormData(index: number){
    return <FormArray>this.imagesListFormData.at(index).get('imageDescription');
  }
  setImageDescription(data: any = null){
    data = data || { language: null, text: null };
    return this.fb.group({
      language: [this.selectedLanguage, Validators.required],
      text: [this.imageDescText, Validators.required],
    });
  }
  setImagesList(data: any = null) {
    data = data || { assetType: null, assetLink: null, filePath: null, description: null };
    return this.fb.group({
      imagePath: [this.imageFilePath, Validators.required],
      imageDescription: this.fb.array(
        data.imageDescription
        ? data.imageDescription.map((x: any) => this.setImageDescription(x))
        : []
      )
    }
    );
  }
  setFormGroup(data: any = null) {
    // debugger
    data = data || {imagesList: null};
    return this.fb.group({
      name: [''], 
      imagesList: this.fb.array(
        data.imagesList ? data.imagesList.map((x: any) => this.setImagesList(x)): []
      )
    });
  }
  createCompanyNews(){
    const formData = this.createAppForm.getRawValue();
    console.log(formData)
    let payload = formData
    this.createCompanyNewsService.CreateCompanyNews(payload).subscribe((res: any) => {
      console.log(res)
    })
  }
  selectLanguage(language : any){
    this.selectedLanguage = language;
    console.log(this.selectedLanguage)
  }
```

Below code is the service file which is subcribed in ** openImagesDialog()** function to receive data from below code

```
export class CompanyNewsDialogServiceService {
  recivedFormData: any;
  imagesListDataRecieved: Subject<CompanyNewsDialogServiceService> = new Subject();
  constructor(private dialog : MatDialog) { }
  confirmImagesListDialog(data: ConfirmDialogData) {
    return this.dialog.open(UploadFileDialogComponent, {data}).afterClosed().subscribe(res =>{
      this.recivedFormData = res;
      console.log('formdata',this.recivedFormData)
      this.imagesListDataRecieved.next(res) ;
    });
  }
}
```

**Currently I'm setting the form again because data is coming from dialog box which is causing loss of data entered before for name fields for the form because of form reset.** I know that is wrong

**I need to patch or set the value inside openImagesDialog() function to only below fields of the payload where i'm getting data for these fields inside openImagesDialog() function respectively.**

Initially below these fields are null. Data for these fields are coming from dialog box after dialog box is closed.

imagePath, imageDescription -> text fields of imagesList array**

Comment: This is way too much code (plus, probably the largest component I’ve ever seen) - please create a simple, reproducable example of your issue.

Comment: Yes, would be nice if you compress the files and just provide minimal snapshots from  files involved in the flow. It is time consuming to follow up on all this.

Comment: Reformed the question in simple manner as per my understanding @MikeOne Please check if it is conveying

Comment: Reformed the question in simple manner as per my understanding @Walid  Please check if it is conveying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set the values based on payload structure what you provided inside the below function. This will not create form reset and assign values to values to respective fields only.

From next time try to simply the question this one also not concise enough to answer what you structured.

```
  openImagesDialog(){
    this.companyNewsDialogServiceService.imagesListDataRecieved.subscribe(res => {
      console.log("imagetest",res)
      this.modalResponseData = res
      this.imageFilePath = this.modalResponseData.data.filepath
      this.imageDescText = this.modalResponseData.data.text
      this.imageFileName = this.modalResponseData.data.filename
      let getImagesList = <FormArray>this.createAppForm.get('imagesList')
      console.log("imageListControl", getImagesList)
      console.log("image",getImagesList.value)
      getImagesList.value.forEach( (x: any) => {
        x.imagePath = this.imageFilePath
        x.imageDescription.forEach( (y: any) => {
          y.text = this.imageDescText
        })
      })
    })
```